# What is the simpliest way to write data to store in React-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using React and Redux (and also Redux-thunk for async tasks) in my app. So, when I need to write some data to `store` as a result of `component` interaction, I use both `action` and `reducer` for this. But is it always necessary? Especially in the situations when there are no `connect`s to the modified field in `component`s? Do I **always** need `action` and `reducer` to write some data to `store`? Or, maybe, there's a method like `setState` in `store`?

Comment: I wrote [Redux-Schema](https://github.com/ddsol/redux-schema) for that. Disclosure: I wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary to write a `action` and a corresponding `reducer` to that action.

This is because `Redux` is built based on the `Flux` architecture. `Flux` architecture uses `actions` and `reducers` to modify a particular state in the state tree. So, it is required and you can't skip it.

If you feel this is too much of boilerplate code, you should try [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Comment: So, Mobx is a framework simplifying `component` > `store` data flow?

Comment: It's more like a state management which takes advantage of ES6 `decorators` and give you simple API to change and modify states without `reducers`

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of storing the data in React with Redux environment

1. storing in component state - if data is only need for the component display or if it doesn't affect anything else in the app, like if you have multi-tab form then storing the current active tab. such data should be stored in component state
2. Storing in redux - any data which you want to access through multiple component or data which need to be present even if component unmounts should be stored in redux.

Now coming to your question, yes to manipulate redux store  you need action, reducer. however if you perform some **common tasks in most of the reducer** you can take it out and create one **common reducer**, in my case we use common reducer to manipulate dropdown data, loading state, changing a specific object ( you can  use "reducerdata" as key in various reducers to store Class Object required for the reducer and write common reducer to change its value)